# How to use Facebook's Flow with Express/Sails

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, sails.js

I want to use Facebook's [Flow](https://flow.org/) with [Sails](https://sailsjs.com/). I read the Flow's guide, and tried it with simple scripts. Now I want to start use it in `Sails` app. I installed `Sails` and `flow-bin` and now don't know what to do, because Flow's typed code need to be recompiled with `Babel`, but I dont think that recompile of `Sails` app is a good idea. I can't find any guide so I need help. Please help me, how I must use `Flow` with `Sails` and `Express`? For `Electron`? What is the best project config for `package.json` `run` scripts? What rules I must follow to reach most result with Flow?

Comment: So this. I also want to badly use Flow with Sails. If you figure out please let me know. At same time as moving to Flow, you would probably have to move to "import module" style no?